# Generic Objective-to-C++ translation strategy

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c

I'd like to expose ObjC notification handlers to my C++ client code.
I'm doing it this way.

1. I wrapped an ObjC object (call it ***X***) inside a C++ object.
2. ***X*** observes the notification and registers a callback (call it ***F***).
3. ***F*** translates the ObjC structures from the notification into their C++ counterparts, calls a **user-registered** global C++ callback function (call it ***FF***). The translated C++ structs become the input arguments of ***FF***.

Now the problem is that the arguments' original ObjC structures are complex, containing multiple layers of ObjC objects that need to be translated.

On my side, the wrapper observer ***F*** needs to do nothing special, just calling the client's ***FF***.

What is the more proper strategy of my translation at this point?

Should I:

1. Translate those structures down to the bottom-level of all their members so that I have equivalent C++ structures to use as the arguments, or,
2. Create a C++ class to wrap these arguments into one object and expose the class interface to user so they can use those C++-wrapped arguments in their C++ implementation, or,
3. Give up on the wrapping idea and ask user to code in ObjC and register their own observer functions directly?

My targeted users are iOS developers that may or may not be Android developers too.

Answer (score 1):

You can mix c++ and objective-c++ in a .mm implementation file. This means you can give a c++ lambda (or block) to the objective-c++ class that references your c++ owner.

something like this:

implementation.mm:

```
@interface Shim : NSObject
{
  std::function<void>() _notify;
}
@end

@implementation Shim
- void register_cpp(std::function<void>() f)
{
  _notify = std::move(f);
}

- (void) my_handler()
{
  if(_notify)
    _notify();
}
@end

struct cpp_class::impl {
  impl()
  : _shim([Shim alloc[init]])
  {
    _shim.register_cpp(std::bind(&impl::callback, this));
  }

private:
  void callback() {
    // do callback here;
  }
  Shim* _shim;
};

cpp_class::cpp_class()
: _impl(new impl)
{
}

cpp_class::~cpp_class()
{
  delete _impl;
}
```

header.h:

```
struct cpp_class{
  cpp_class();
  ~cpp_class();

private:
  struct impl;
  impl* _impl;
};
```

In reality you'll want to be careful to ensure that objects still exist when doing callbacks (argues for weak_ptr::lock(), enable_shared_from_this, etc.) since objective-c likes to put callbacks onto a thread's run loop (basically a queue) and that means your c++ object can go away before the callback arrives - but this code should give you the right idea.